# How to efficiently merge two hashes in Ruby C API?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am writing a C extension for Ruby that really needs to merge two hashes, however the rb_hash_merge() function is STATIC in Ruby 1.8.6. I have tried instead to use:

```
rb_funcall(hash1, rb_intern("merge"), 1, hash2);
```

but this is much too slow, and performance is very critical in this application.

Does anyone know how to go about performing this merge with efficiency and speed in mind?

(Note I have tried simply looking at the source for rb_hash_merge() and replicating it but it is RIDDLED with other static functions, which are themselves riddled with yet more static functions so it seems almost impossible to disentangle...i need another way)

Comment: "performance is very critical in this application." == not Ruby, IMHO.
What you mention looks like the only approach without building in the fragile code.

Comment: I don't mind if the code is fragile, just so long as it works on ruby 1.8.6 and ruby 1.9.1 (even with the help of preprocessor defs)

Comment: I made some tests, and looks like you won't be able to get much using the standard API... I'll post the code within an answer just for formatting sake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, looks like might be not possible to optimize within the published API.

Test code:

```
#extconf.rb
require 'mkmf'
dir_config("hello")
create_makefile("hello")


// hello.c
#include "ruby.h"

static VALUE rb_mHello;
static VALUE rb_cMyCalc;

static void calc_mark(void *f) { }
static void calc_free(void *f) { }
static VALUE calc_alloc(VALUE klass) { return Data_Wrap_Struct(klass, calc_mark, calc_free, NULL); }

static VALUE calc_init(VALUE obj) { return Qnil; }

static VALUE calc_merge(VALUE obj, VALUE h1, VALUE h2) {
  return rb_funcall(h1, rb_intern("merge"), 1, h2);
}

static VALUE
calc_merge2(VALUE obj, VALUE h1, VALUE h2)
{
  VALUE h3 = rb_hash_new();
  VALUE keys;
  VALUE akey;
  keys = rb_funcall(h1, rb_intern("keys"), 0);
  while (akey = rb_each(keys)) {
    rb_hash_aset(h3, akey, rb_hash_aref(h1, akey));
  }
  keys = rb_funcall(h2, rb_intern("keys"), 0);
  while (akey = rb_each(keys)) {
    rb_hash_aset(h3, akey, rb_hash_aref(h2, akey));
  }
  return h3;
}

static VALUE
calc_merge3(VALUE obj, VALUE h1, VALUE h2)
{
  VALUE keys;
  VALUE akey;
  keys = rb_funcall(h1, rb_intern("keys"), 0);
  while (akey = rb_each(keys)) {
    rb_hash_aset(h2, akey, rb_hash_aref(h1, akey));
  }
  return h2;
}

void
Init_hello()
{
  rb_mHello = rb_define_module("Hello");
  rb_cMyCalc = rb_define_class_under(rb_mHello, "Calculator", rb_cObject);
  rb_define_alloc_func(rb_cMyCalc, calc_alloc);
  rb_define_method(rb_cMyCalc, "initialize", calc_init, 0);
  rb_define_method(rb_cMyCalc, "merge", calc_merge, 2);
  rb_define_method(rb_cMyCalc, "merge2", calc_merge, 2);
  rb_define_method(rb_cMyCalc, "merge3", calc_merge, 2);
}


# test.rb
require "hello"

h1 = Hash.new()
h2 = Hash.new()

1.upto(100000) { |x| h1[x] = x+1; }
1.upto(100000) { |x| h2["#{x}-12"] = x+1; }

c = Hello::Calculator.new()

puts c.merge(h1, h2).keys.length if ARGV[0] == "1"
puts c.merge2(h1, h2).keys.length if ARGV[0] == "2"
puts c.merge3(h1, h2).keys.length if ARGV[0] == "3"
```

Now the test results:

```
$ time ruby test.rb

real    0m1.021s
user    0m0.940s
sys     0m0.080s
$ time ruby test.rb 1
200000

real    0m1.224s
user    0m1.148s
sys     0m0.076s
$ time ruby test.rb 2
200000

real    0m1.219s
user    0m1.132s
sys     0m0.084s
$ time ruby test.rb 3
200000

real    0m1.220s
user    0m1.128s
sys     0m0.092s
```

So it looks like we might shave off at maximum ~0.004s on a 0.2s operation.

Given that there's probably not that much besides setting the values, there might not be that much space for further optimizations. Maybe try to hack the ruby source itself - but at that point you no longer really develop "extension" but rather change the language, so it probably won't work.

If the join of hashes is something that you need to do many times in the C part - then probably using the internal data structures and only exporting them into Ruby hash in the final pass would be the only way of optimizing things.

p.s. The initial skeleton for the code borrowed from [this excellent tutorial](http://people.apache.org/~rooneg/talks/ruby-extensions/ruby-extensions.html)

Comment: wow! thanks for your very thorough analysis of the situation! :) so, yes based on your results it looks like i have to find another way of going about it... :)

cheers!

Comment: you're welcome :-) If you find the time to experiment and it is relevant to your situation - maybe you could check how well does the similar code in Lua perform, using tables, and post the comparison here. I think the solution using the datastructures from Lua should be a bit faster.